# Pause programmatically video player mpv

Tags: linux, mpv

I would like to know if there is a way to send a message to a running process on linux ?

For example, is it possible to programmatically "pause" a video launched with `mpv`.

Comment: There is  no general way. The process itself would have to implement something which allowed it to receive messages from outside. Just for pausing though, you can send the process a SIGSTOP.

Comment: `kill -s STOP 13021` and  `kill -s CONT 13021`. Thanks, that's a brilliant work around ! Is it maybe possible to send a key signal too ?

Comment: What is a "key signal"?

Comment: sorry keystroke. Like Escape, Spacebar...

Comment: I use : `xdotool key --window "$(xdotool search --class mpv)" p` The key P is used to pause the video.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To control `mpv` remotely (eg from another terminal session) you can also start it with the option

```
--input-ipc-server=/tmp/mpvsocket
```

and control it by issuing commands like this:

```
echo '{ "command": ["set_property", "pause", true] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket
```

See `man mpv` for (many) more details.

edit: see also `mpv --list-properties`

edit2: The most simple way I've found to "toggle" pause/play is

`{"command": ["cycle", "pause"]}`

Comment: with this option by default mpv creates a single socket, which is for the last mpv instance opened. to get multiple sockets per PID, use the [mpvSockets plugin](https://github.com/wis/mpvSockets)

Comment: Wish I had come across that plugin sooner o_o. Ended up writing [my own solution](https://github.com/seanbreckenridge/mpv-sockets) to handle communicating with multiple IPC servers by using the epoch time to create multiple sockets.

Answer (score 10):

`kill -s STOP $(pidof mpv)` and `kill -s CONT $(pidof mpv)`

or better :

`xdotool key --window "$(xdotool search --class mpv)" p`

The key "P", is set by default to pause the video.

Answer (score 8):

It's possible to control mpv through IPC. From the manual `mpv(1)`:

```
--input-ipc-server=<filename>
       Enable the IPC support and create the listening socket at the given path.

       On  Linux and Unix, the given path is a regular filesystem path.
       On Windows, named pipes are used, so the path refers to the pipe namespace (\\.\pipe\<name>). If the \\.\pipe\ prefix is missing, mpv will add it automatically before creating the pipe, so --input-ipc-server=/tmp/mpv-socket and --input-ipc-server=\\.\pipe\tmp\mpv-socket are equivalent for IPC on Windows.

       See JSON IPC for details.
```

A couple of examples:

```
$ echo 'cycle pause'   | socat - /tmp/mpv-socket
$ echo 'playlist-prev' | socat - /tmp/mpv-socket
$ echo 'playlist-next' | socat - /tmp/mpv-socket
```

See `mpv(1)` to learn more.

See also:

- https://alexherbo2.github.io/blog/mpv/command-line-controller/
- https://gist.github.com/dwgill/a66769e0edef69c04d3b