# mpv linux changing video window size

Tags: linux, video, mpv

I'm streaming video using mpv on my ubuntu using this command line

```
mpv http://myserverUrl:1234 --input-ipc-server=/tmp/mpvsocket -v --geometry=400x320+20+30
```

It is streaming the video and I managed to stop using `echo '{ "command": ["set_property", "pause", true] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket` after reading [Pause programmatically video player mpv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35013075/pause-programmatically-video-player-mpv]) post.

But i also need to resize the geometry without killing the video process and restart another new mpv instance using the new geometry size. Is that possible? I tried using

```
echo "set geometry=1270x300" | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket
```

but doesn't work.

anyone can point me to right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: don't really use it but the example you says "works" sends JSON, so why don't you try the same pattern echo "{ "command": ["set_property", "geometry", "1270x300"] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket