# Get full path of currently playing file in mpv

Tags: linux, mpv

Is there a way to get the full path of the currently playing file from `mpv`, after `mpv` has been launched?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41780401/9348376) question but it doesn't show how to get properties, just how send commands.

Edit: by 'get the full path', I mean from programatically; from another program or a terminal, not by using `mpv` commands/keybindings on the `mpv` application itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you have to start `mpv` with the `--input-ipc-server` option, or put that in your `mpv.conf` file. That would look like:

`--input-ipc-server=/tmp/mpvsocket`

or without the dashes in the `mpv.conf` file:

`input-ipc-server=/tmp/mpvsocket`

The socket is connected to the most recent `mpv` instance launched with the same `input-ipc-server`.

Then, you can use a command like:

```sh
echo '{ "command": ["get_property", "<some property>"] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket
```

For example:

```sh
$ echo '{ "command": ["get_property", "path"] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket
{"data":"01 - Don't Know Why.mp3","request_id":0,"error":"success"}
```

You can get a list of properties by doing `mpv --list-properties`

To get the full path, combine the `working-directory` and `path` properties. The response can be parsed with `jq`, so for the desired output:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

SOCKET='/tmp/mpvsocket'

# pass the property as the first argument
mpv_communicate() {
  printf '{ "command": ["get_property", "%s"] }\n' "$1" | socat - "${SOCKET}" | jq -r ".data"
}

WORKING_DIR="$(mpv_communicate "working-directory")"
FILEPATH="$(mpv_communicate "path")"

printf "%s/%s\n" "$WORKING_DIR" "$FILEPATH"
```

Edit: I've since added additional error handling to what the above script became; [`mpv-currently-playing`](https://github.com/seanbreckenridge/mpv-sockets/blob/master/mpv-currently-playing). Shouldn't always try to compute an absolute path unless you're sure its playing a local file. If its a URL, that could end up messing up the scheme/location

Comment: been playing with this a bunch more since I left this question; left my random scripts up [here](https://github.com/seanbreckenridge/mpv-sockets) incase anyone wants more examples.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
echo '{ "command": ["get_property", "playlist"] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket |jq '.data[].filename'

"/mnt/d6/media/vid.mp4"
```

ie

```
# -- 1
echo '{ "command": ["get_property", "playlist"] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket # |jq . '.data[].filename'

{"data":[{"filename":"/mnt/d6/media/vid.mp4","current":true,"playing":true}],"request_id":0,"error":"success"}


# -- 2
echo '{ "command": ["get_property", "playlist"] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket |jq . # '.data[].filename'

{
  "data": [
    {
      "filename": "/mnt/d6/media/vid.mp4",
      "current": true,
      "playing": true
    }
  ],
  "request_id": 0,
  "error": "success"
}


# -- 3
echo '{ "command": ["get_property", "playlist"] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket |jq '.data[].filename'

"/mnt/d6/media/vid.mp4"


# -- 4
enjoy ;)


# -- jq
https://www.baeldung.com/linux/jq-command-json
https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/

jq is like sed for JSON data :

you can use it to slice and filter and map and transform structured data
with the same ease that sed, awk, grep and 
friends let you play with text.
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your mpv config file to show full path upon opening

```
osd-playing-msg=${path}
```

Comment: Guess its related, but wasn't exactly my question (as my answer described) -- I wanted to get the path from a terminal or another program, not from within `mpv` itself. Have updated the question to make that more obvious